# Extract content of iPhone backups

Tags: windows, gratis, backup, itunes, data-extraction

I have iTunes backup files stored [at standard location](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204215) in

```
%APPDATA%\Roaming\Apple Computer\MobileSync\Backup\
```

I need a **tool to extract notes, contacts and other information from these backup files** even if the original iPhone is no longer available.

**My requirements:**

- Windows Vista or higher (but on given computer I have Windows Vista)
- free
- no extraction limits (or limit no smaller than 300 records in each category)

I know that for example notes are synced with Microsoft Outlook, but I don't have Outlook at that computer.

If you know significantly good software, which does not support Windows Vista or which is trialware, but can export all data from backup within its trial period, I will upvote such an answer too, even it I won't mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2):

[iPhone Backup Extractor](http://www.reincubate.com/labs/iphone-backup-extractor-how-extract-files-iphone-backup-windows/#http://www.reincubate.com/res/i/labs/iphonebe/iphone-backup-extractor-screen-shots/file-menu.png) works on Windows, Mac OS X and Linux and with ALL iDevices or iOSes. It can recover contacts, pictures, call histories, MMS, SMS and text messages, video, voice-mail, calendar entries, notes, app files, saved games just about everything. Convert database files to CSV, VCARDS and ICAL so they can easily exported to excel,outlook,webmails etc.

Comment: Their are a couple more i found on the web although i have never used any of them beside the one i mentioned above but they seems promising maybe the can be of some help. [itunesextractor](http://www.itunesextractor.com/),[iphonebackupviewer](http://www.imactools.com/iphonebackupviewer/),[ibackupextractor](https://www.wideanglesoftware.com/ibackupextractor/)..
Hope this helps!!! Cheers!!

Comment: I checked today and found that the tool you recommend does not fulfill the requirements anymore. Maybe it was free and unlimited before, but not now.

Answer (score 2):

They are many similar programs for this purpose. Among them, **[iPhone Backup Extractor](http://www.iphonetransferrecovery.com/tutorials/iphone-backup-extractor-mac.html)** is the best in performance. It finds all iPhone, iPod Touch and iPad backups on your computer and lets you recover your files with ease.

Use iBackup Extractor to view the backup of your Contacts, Calendars, Photos, Internet browsing history, Call logs, Notes, SMS, iMessages, Voice Mails and more. Simply choose the type of file you wish to extract in iBackup Extractor and click on "Copy".

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is that software free and without extraction limits as per requirements in the question? Your answer will be helpful if you can recommend backup software fulfilling requirements given in the question above. Otherwise, it may be downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

If you have backed up your iPhone data with iTunes, you can directly extract data from iTunes backup file without your iPhone. What you need is a third-party tool to extract data from iTunes.
I have ever tried to export contacts and sms messages from iTunes with a free software,[Free Jihosoft iTunes Backup Extractor](http://www.itunesextractor.com/), which helps a lot to extract data from iPhone backup.

Steps to [extract data from iPhone backup](http://www.itunesextractor.com/extract-data-from-iphone-backup-free.html)

1. Download and launch iPhone Backup Extractor and select the backup file you need extract data from.
2. Select the data that you want to extract, such as contacts, whatsApp messages, text messages, call history, photos, videos, etc.
3. Preview and check the scanned files, then click “Recover” to extract files from iPhone backup.